# Can someone find the faults in my code[open]?

Tags: c++

Hey guys new to the site because I really can't figure out what I am missing here. For my class we have projects that we do on www.hackerrank.com and with our submissions all it tells us if we fail any of the test data. I am unable to satisfy all of 6 tests and I can't tell what I am missing. I passed the sample data they gave me so I can't go off that. I was hoping you guys could skim through my code and tell me if I may not be taking in something that could be tested. Here is a link to the problem https://docs.google.com/document/d/1t3CdFT3QN6lCBhVHRE4rn0IsPvGGoJzywHTufp3qKBk/edit?usp=sharing .And here is the code.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;


int main() {
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
queue<int> myqueue;
int myint;
int shares = 0;
int sum = 0;
int numbers = 0;
while(cin >> myint)
    {
    if(myint > 0)
    {
        myqueue.push(myint);
        sum += myint;

        if(numbers < 10)
        {
            numbers++;
        }
        else
        {
            sum = sum - myqueue.front();
            myqueue.pop();
        }
    }
    else
    {

        if (myqueue.back() < (sum/numbers))
        {
            if(shares <= 0)
            {
                cout << "short sell" << endl;
                shares--;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "sell" << endl;
                shares--;
            }
        }
        else if(myqueue.back() > (sum/numbers))
        {
            cout << "buy" << endl;
            shares++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "nothing" << endl;
        }
    }
}


return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: Don't put "[open]" or "[solved]" in your title. When you accept and answer, it is marked as having an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are doing an integer division to calculate your "10-period simple". This will truncate the value and might be equal to the current stock price, instead of higher.

Cast either `sum` or `numbers` to a `float` or `double` on these lines:

```
if (myqueue.back() < (sum/numbers))

else if(myqueue.back() > (sum/numbers))
```

Comment: Yup I just assumed that with the test data that the one "nothing" result was from a truncated int but no it actually is a perfect 7. I knew it was something dumb I was missing. Thank you for the help!